# Vim "fast" search gets disabled after adding `.vimrc`

Tags: vim

I made a clean install of a the new version of Linux which includes `vim 8.0.586` on my machine and noticed a cool feature in `vim`:  When you hit `/` and start typing the word to search for, it actively highlights the matches in black in the text (before hitting Enter and jumping to that word).  Then after completing the pattern and hitting Enter it highlights the words in black and jumps to the first match.

Surprisingly enough, after adding the `.vimrc` (to customize `vim` at the start-up, ...) this feature gets disabled!  Does anybody else have the same experience and a solution?

Comment: `:set incsearch`?

Comment: Thanks! The issue solved :-)!  And if someone is curious to know the reason, `help defaults.vim` explains that in case `.v.mrc` is not available `defaults.vim` is loaded instead, and recommends to include `defaults.vim` in a custom `.vimrc` if one wants to have that.

Answer (score 0):

You've experienced the effects of the *defaults settings* as long as you didn't have your own `~/.vimrc`. This is explained by `:help defaults.vim`:

> If Vim is started normally and no user vimrc file is found, the
>   $VIMRUTIME/defaults.vim script is loaded.  This will set 'compatible' off,
>   switch on syntax highlighting and a few more things.

It continues with:

> If you create your own .vimrc, it is
>   recommended to add this line somewhere near the top:
>           unlet! skip_defaults_vim
>           source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
>   Then Vim works like before you had a .vimrc.

The particular setting you're asking about is `:set incsearch`.